# open-api generator for python not working for subtypes or anyOf/allOf

Tags: python, command-line-interface, openapi, openapi-generator

Here's my yaml (**setup.yml**):

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.2
info:
  title: "My Setup"
  description: "Some old nonsense"
  version: 1.0.0
  contact:
    name: "Tom Riddle"
    email: "tom@not-a-muggle.co.uk"
    url: "https://deatheaters-anonymous.org"
  termsOfService: MIT
servers: []
paths: {}
components:
  schemas:
    CodeValue:
      type: integer
      minimum: 200
      maximum: 302
    AgeGroup:
      type: string
      enum: [baby, child, teen, adult, old]
    Age:
      anyOf:
        - type: string
          enum: [baby, child, teen, adult, old]
        - type: integer
```

Running openapi-generator (downloaded from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/4.3.1 ---> **openapi-generator-cli-4.3.1.jar** and run the the CLI using `java -jar openapi-generator-cli.jar generate -g python -i setup.yml -o src`) I obtain the following result:

1. `src/openapi_client/models` contains `age.py` and `age_group.py` ... BUT NO `code_value.py` ---> **why??!**
2. the file `age_group.py` looks fine. The enum is there, I can see the values, *etc.* Great.
3. the file `age.py` does not even resemble the the yaml definition (see below). There is no checking if the value is an integer or string (ie `anyOf` is not properly implemented), and no trace of mention of the enum. In fact it is nowhere to be found in the generated project structure. ---> **why??!**

```py
# coding: utf-8

"""
    My Setup

    Some old nonsense  # noqa: E501

    The version of the OpenAPI document: 1.0.0
    Contact: tom@not-a-muggle.co.uk
    Generated by: https://openapi-generator.tech
"""


import pprint
import re  # noqa: F401

import six

from openapi_client.configuration import Configuration


class Age(object):
    """NOTE: This class is auto generated by OpenAPI Generator.
    Ref: https://openapi-generator.tech

    Do not edit the class manually.
    """

    """
    Attributes:
      openapi_types (dict): The key is attribute name
                            and the value is attribute type.
      attribute_map (dict): The key is attribute name
                            and the value is json key in definition.
    """
    openapi_types = {
    }

    attribute_map = {
    }

    def __init__(self, local_vars_configuration=None):  # noqa: E501
        """Age - a model defined in OpenAPI"""  # noqa: E501
        if local_vars_configuration is None:
            local_vars_configuration = Configuration()
        self.local_vars_configuration = local_vars_configuration
        self.discriminator = None

    def to_dict(self):
        """Returns the model properties as a dict"""
        result = {}

        for attr, _ in six.iteritems(self.openapi_types):
            value = getattr(self, attr)
            if isinstance(value, list):
                result[attr] = list(map(
                    lambda x: x.to_dict() if hasattr(x, "to_dict") else x,
                    value
                ))
            elif hasattr(value, "to_dict"):
                result[attr] = value.to_dict()
            elif isinstance(value, dict):
                result[attr] = dict(map(
                    lambda item: (item[0], item[1].to_dict())
                    if hasattr(item[1], "to_dict") else item,
                    value.items()
                ))
            else:
                result[attr] = value

        return result

    def to_str(self):
        """Returns the string representation of the model"""
        return pprint.pformat(self.to_dict())

    def __repr__(self):
        """For `print` and `pprint`"""
        return self.to_str()

    def __eq__(self, other):
        """Returns true if both objects are equal"""
        if not isinstance(other, Age):
            return False

        return self.to_dict() == other.to_dict()

    def __ne__(self, other):
        """Returns true if both objects are not equal"""
        if not isinstance(other, Age):
            return True

        return self.to_dict() != other.to_dict()
```

Comment: Note, have also tried with 3.0.0, 3.0.1. But that makes no difference. And swagger codegen also didn't help (besides which I need to use the OAS3 standard).

Comment: Please try the latest master of openapi-generator to see if the issue still exists. There's a new `python-experimental` generator that you may also want to give it a try.

Comment: @WilliamCheng I have used openapi-generator v4, but to no avail. I also want to know whether or not these classes in general contain the internal checks. Try for example very basic things like integer + a minimum condition … the generated class has absolutely no checks of this minimum. I really don't get it. But I will try python-experimental. Thanks.

Comment: @WilliamCheng just tried `python-experimental` with my current version of openapi-generator (cli). It looks v. promising! Thanks for the tip! Just a question. To actually use the generated classes (the models) I would just need the `models` folder + `model_utils.py`, right? Are there examples of this? Basically I only care about the models, not the api.

Comment: @WilliamCheng also any idea how to use the extra cli options (e. g. `generateSourceCodeOnly`)? Cannot find this anywhere.

Comment: Please open an issue via http://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/new for tracking so that the openapi-generator community can help you out.

Comment: @WilliamCheng have posted it here https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/9127

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using the current (v6.0.1) [python-experimental](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/python-experimental.md#metadata) openapi-generator client

The current python-experimental client generates anyOf and allOf models.

- [here are anyOf endpoints](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/samples/openapi3/client/3_0_3_unit_test/python-experimental/docs/apis/tags/AnyOfApi.md)
- [here are allOf endpoints](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/samples/openapi3/client/3_0_3_unit_test/python-experimental/docs/apis/tags/AllOfApi.md)

[And primitive models like codeValue are also generated](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/samples/openapi3/client/petstore/python-experimental/petstore_api/model/number_with_validations.py#L71) like so:

```
class NumberWithValidations(
    _SchemaValidator(
        inclusive_maximum=20,
        inclusive_minimum=10,
    ),
    NumberSchema
):
    """NOTE: This class is auto generated by OpenAPI Generator.
    Ref: https://openapi-generator.tech
    Do not edit the class manually.
    """
    pass
```

And [tests of it here](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/samples/openapi3/client/petstore/python-experimental/tests_manual/test_number_with_validations.py)

And here are tests:

- [an allOf endpoint test](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/samples/openapi3/client/3_0_3_unit_test/python-experimental/test/test_paths/test_request_body_post_allof_request_body/test_post.py#L37)
- [an allOf model test](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/samples/openapi3/client/3_0_3_unit_test/python-experimental/test/test_models/test_allof.py#L23)
- [an anyOf endpoint test](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/samples/openapi3/client/3_0_3_unit_test/python-experimental/test/test_paths/test_request_body_post_anyof_request_body/test_post.py#L37)
- [an anyOf model test](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/samples/openapi3/client/3_0_3_unit_test/python-experimental/test/test_models/test_anyof.py#L23)
- there is even [a test of a model that combines oneOf, anyOf, and allOf here](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/samples/openapi3/client/3_0_3_unit_test/python-experimental/test/test_models/test_allof_combined_with_anyof_oneof.py#L58)